# I get a ValueError that I do not understand

Tags: python, list

I am stuck and do not understand why my code does not work. Could anyone help me? I get a ValueError saying `'Malin' is not in the list`.

```
for line in text_file:
    clean_line = line.translate(None, ',.:;"-_')
    list_of_a_line = clean_line.split()
    #print list_of_a_line
    #How do do I remove both quotation marks?
    for word in list_of_a_line:
        word = word.lower()
        for one_focus_word in focus_words:
            if word.lower() == one_focus_word.lower():
                sentiment_point = 0
                print word
                index_number = list_of_a_line.index(word)
                print index_number
```

When I block the line that says `print list_of_a_line.index(word)` the code works. So I can print `word` and I can print `list_of_a_line` (see that list that gets printed below)
`["internet", "IPS", "IPSs", "cobb", "comcast", "centrylink", "paris", "malin" ,"trump"]`

Feel free to give any other comments about my code.

Answer (score 1):

You do:

```
for word in list_of_a_line:
    word = word.lower()
```

and later in this loop:

```
            index_number = list_of_a_line.index(word)
```

That means you look for the lower case version of the word in the list and not the original version it contains. This raises a value error.

You can use `enumerate` to get the index of the word without using `.index()`:

```
for index_number, word in enumerate(list_of_a_line):
    for one_focus_word in focus_words:
        if word.lower() == one_focus_word.lower():
            sentiment_point = 0
            print word
            print index_number
```

Answer (score 0):

That means 'Malin' is not in your list, that's why you get an exception.

i.e:

```
x = ['a', 'b']
x.index('c')
```

ValueError: 'c' is not in list

You can handle this exception inside a try/except block, or understand why the word is not in the list

The docs about the [index method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_index.htm)

> This method returns index of the found object otherwise raise an
>   exception indicating that value does not find.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because

```
word = word.lower()
```

so 'Malin' isn't in your list, but 'malin' is. Assuming it was there.